# Expressions in Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I want to understand how expressions work in Ocaml.
For example, I have :

```
type expr =
 Int of int
 | Var of string
 | Sum of expr * expr
 | Diff of expr * expr
 | Mult of expr * expr
 | Div of expr * expr
```

How can I recognise if an element is an expression?

I was think to something like  `expr -> expr -> bool` :

```
let subexpression express1 express2 =
 if express1 express1 then true else false 
  
 let E1 = 3 x 8 in
  let E2 = 5/6 in
   if subexpression E1 E2 then print_strin "true" else print_string "false"
```

I haven't test the code because this is what I'm thinking, but actually I don't know how to write it...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  An expression is some construct that may be evaluated to return a value.  A function is not an expression but the application of a function to all the required parameters is an expression since it can be evaluated to a value.

Comment: So, to be clear, function application isn't the only type of expression.  Any syntactic construct within a function or at the global level that is evaluated to a value is an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be clear on whether you're asking about expressions in OCaml generally or values of the type `expr` that you define here.

Because OCaml is a strongly typed language, you can't have a value of type `expr` that's not well formed. So there's no meaningful function to test whether something of type `expr` is an expression. (You could define a function that always returns true.)

On the other hand, your proposed function has *two* expression parameters. This doesn't make a lot of sense either. What is the purpose of these two parameters?

Other parts of your question suggest that you want to determine whether one expression is a subexpression of another. That's a different question entirely.

You can look through an value of type `expr` by working recursively through the different cases. The basic framework of a function for traversing such a value would look something like this:

```
let myfunc expr =
    match expr with
    | Int n -> (* do something n, an int *)
    | Var s -> (* do something with s, a string *)
    | Sum (e1, e2) -> some_combination_of (myfunc e1) (myfunc e2)
    | Diff (e1, e2) -> some_combination_of (myfunc e1) (myfunc e2)
    | Mult (e1, e2) -> some_combination_of (myfunc e1) (myfunc e2)
    | Div (e1, e2) -> some_combination_of (myfunc e1) (myfunc e2)
```

It's hard to say more than this because your question is hard to understand, (and it frankly doesn't look like you've put in very much work on it yet).

Comment: Ok, with the help of the other post I think I got it thanks.