# Expressions and subexpressions Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm going to ask something that isn't clear for me so I'll try to be the most exaustive I can...

How can I check if an expression is a subexpression of another?

For example, here :

```
type expr =
 Int of int
 | Var of string
 | Sum of expr * expr
 | Diff of expr * expr
 | Mult of expr * expr
 | Div of expr * expr
```

If I have one expression (choosen between those above), how can I recognize if it's a subexpression of another inside the list?

Can you show me some real code? Because I read some stuffs of the internet and I tried to write something but really I don't know what I should write.

Comment: An expression is a tree. You can traverse an expression and visit every node in the tree. At each node you can check whether the subtree rooted at that node is equal to some given other expression. This is a simple (in fact crude) way to get your desired result. To compare two expressions you can use the ordinary comparison operator `=`.

Comment: Mmmh ok sounds good, I know how to handle tree with recursive functions but how can I apply these concepts to expressions?

Comment: A value of type `expr` (as you define it) is a tree. The leaves are constructed with `Int` and `Var`. The other constructors create internal nodes of the tree.

Comment: Aaaah ok so if an expression is Int or Var it means that we have to stop the search right?

Comment: It's hard to see what the alternative would be as these leaf nodes have no children. :-)

Comment: Doesn't the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62613808/1048572) already give you some ideas?

Comment: @Bergi yes it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jeffreysco mentions, it's recursion on a tree structure.

Concretely, if `e1` is the "large" expression within which you want to see if you can find `e2`:

1. First check if `e1` is equal to `e2`
2. Otherwise pattern-match on `e1` and recurse on the subexpressions of `Sum` `Diff` `Mult` `Div`

```ml
let rec is_subexp e1 e2 =
  if e1 = e2 then true
  else match e1 with
  | Int _ | Var _ -> false
  | Sum(e3,e4) -> is_subexp e3 e2 || is_subexp e4 e2
  ...
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you call "Sum", and its return is called on "e2,e3" and "e4,e2"... just to check all the cases? And why "||" instead of "&&"?

Comment: @MichealRoss `Sum` is not "called", it's pattern-matched. And yes, you want to check all the cases: `e2` is a subexpression of the sum (`e1`)  when it's either inside the first operand (`e3`) or second operand (`e4`).